# PHI function to list relative primes

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function, math-software, coprime

I am using a website called [dcode](https://www.dcode.fr/euler-totient) to input numbers into the PHI function, and then receive an output of numbers relatively prime with my input.

The website, unfortunately, limits output to just 500 relatively prime numbers. For my testing this is too low, preferably I would like a complete list.

Could anyone recommend a desktop software which does not have such limitations? It can be for either Windows or Linux. I know about Matlab, but was hoping there was already a program which does what I want, without me having to learn a new scripting language.

Comment: Use PARI/GP , with the built in function gcd you can easily print the numbers coprime to any given number $n$ : n=2310;for(j=0,n-1,if(gcd(j,n)==1,print1(j," ")))

Comment: @Peter I appreciate your answer, however I thought using the Euler's Totient Phi would be much faster than just checking the GCD for each number?

Comment: This function returns only the number of coprime integers in the range $[1,n-1]$ , not the integers with this property.

Comment: @Peter Which is faster, using the website's approach or your answer? I plan to check large values for n.

Comment: If $n$ is large, you will have very many numbers in the output. I do not think that it will make a great difference.

Comment: @Peter One final question about the syntax of PARI/GP. After I check gcd(j,n)==1 how can I add another if() which is only checked when gcd(j,n)==1 otherwise the loop continues iterating? At the moment I am doing if(gcd(j,n)==1 && ... which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easily solved problem, and doesn't require any sort of advanced tools. As Peter said, Euler's Totient is only for computing the *number* of coprimes for a given *n*. To actually calculate them, I guarantee that website is doing exactly what Peter suggested: checking the GCD of each possibility. That shouldn't take very long.

Here's a complete Python program to do that, for numbers passed as arguments to the script. (i.e. you'd call it like `python3 coprimes.py 47 87` to list the coprimes for, separately, `47` and `87`). It'll list the results, and then give the quantity and time required to produce them, for each argument in turn.

It's quite fast. I tried it with the value `4636436`, which has `1987032` coprimes. It took my Linux machine 8 seconds to compute *and* list them all. And honestly, the time spent printing them to the terminal takes up roughly half of that time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import time
from pprint import pprint
from math import gcd

def coprimes(n):
    return list([x for x in range(1, n) if gcd(x, n) == 1])

def main(args):
    for n in args:
        t1 = time.monotonic()
        cp = coprimes(int(n))
        pprint(cp, compact=True)
        t2 = time.monotonic()
        print(f"Found {len(cp)} coprimes for {n} in {(t2 - t1):.6f} seconds")
        if n is not args[-1]:
            print("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The output:

```
$ python3 coprimes.py 47 87
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46]
Found 46 coprimes for 47 in 0.000209 seconds


[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 31, 32,
 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 56, 59, 61, 62, 64,
 65, 67, 68, 70, 71, 73, 74, 76, 77, 79, 80, 82, 83, 85, 86]
Found 56 coprimes for 87 in 0.000224 seconds
```